# MYSQL Trigger based on query

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have table called company. Structure as follows:

```
company
-----------------------------
company_id       integer
company_name     varchar
fk_company_type  varchar
created_date     date
```

fk_company_type is foreign key with the following values:

```
HQ
SITE
CUSTOMER
SUPPLIER
```

My issue I only want one record in company table to be HQ (HeadQuarters). Therefore I need a trigger that will count how many HQ in the company table. If it the count returns 1 and the new record being inserted has value of fk_company_type = HQ then the insert is aborted.

Any help on the best way to do this will be much appreciated. Also I already have a trigger which generates a UUID for the company_id and date. Hopefully this does not effect what I am trying to achieve.

phpadmin trigger (time: BEFORE, event: INSERT)

```
BEGIN
SET NEW.company_id=UUID_SHORT();
SET NEW.created_date=current_timestamp();
END
```

I've tried the basics layout and got as far as this but it produces a syntax error, here is how far I got.

```
BEGIN   
    IF fk_company_type = "HQ" THEN
        DECLARE valid_number int;
        SELECT COUNT(*) into valid_number FROM company WHERE fk_company_type = "HQ";
        IF valid_number > 0 THEN 

                -- some error message
        END IF;
    END IF;
    SET NEW.company_id=UUID_SHORT();
    SET NEW.created_date=current_timestamp();
END
```

Comment: You would be better off making a different headquarters table, and only allowing unique company_ids in it

Comment: Thanks but not an option.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to abort an insert is to set a value to an illegal one.
for example if the column is set to NOT NULL then set the value to NULL and the insert will fail.

The question/issue of how you tell people it has failed depends on your application.

Comment: Thanks my trigger coding is no coding and I'm after some help on writing it. I've tried the basics but get  syntax error.

Comment: Please see above for updated code of how far I've got to on the trigger

Comment: Without seeing the syntax error I am guessing.  When you use a function like count() you need a GROUP BY clause: select count(company_ID) into valid_number from company where fk_company_type="HQ" group by company_ID.